# can i send my testnet ethers to external testnet account?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, testnets, sendtransaction

I am rich now.
I installed geth on ubuntu,
created a testnet chain,
made an ethereum account,
mined 100 ethers, and
tried sending 20 ethers to another testnet ethereum account.

It seems I am learning not bad.

I was wondering if it is possible to send  those test ethers to another test wallet account (metamask kovan maybe?) from my geth console?

like this

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: '0x3f65...e31', to: '0x6c...BDf', value: web3.toWei(20, "ether")})
```

(okay, one question at a time)
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- that 100 ethers are in your **local testnet network** and can be transfer to another account in the same network not a public network like **ropsten** or **kovan**
- to gaining testnet ether in each of these networks you should go to the related faucet and request some
- in the other hand you can connect your metamask wallet to your local chain

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.  I couldn't connect my metamask wallet to my localchain through localhost:8545. Should i try other similar wallets?